# Java Multiple Screens create/use

Tags: java

I have not yet created a GUI in Java, thus I'm wondering how I can create and use multiple Windows. I want to work with the following Windows:

1. Splash Screen
2. Login Window (Create and Load Game)
3. Main Window

The Main Window contains three buttons:

- If Button1 is clicked, then show Window1.
- If Button2 is clicked, then show Window2.
- If Button3 is clicked, then show Window3.

How can I do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm Reading all online tutorials, but unfortently can't understand. I know that JFrame, can't be multipe, and JPanel, don't fit here..

Comment: In Java, you can use a [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) to create a new window and a [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) to create a button.

Comment: ok so what i think you should look at is using different scenes

Comment: @ArachnidHivemind   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/M8x7r.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VGWOW.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWmWs.png
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/j4JyM.png
  [5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SoFlr.png
  [6]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mOhvu.png   Couldn't added more than 2 links in topic :(

Comment: Oof sorry about this but i don't really get what that was supposed to do. If you post some code ill try to help you with that but I'm not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started, here is an example:

```
private void run() {
    JFrame main = createMain();
    populateMain(main.getContentPane());
    main.setVisible(true);
}

private JFrame createMain() {
    JFrame result = new JFrame();
    result.setTitle("Main");
    result.setSize(400, 300);
    result.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    return result;
}

private void populateMain(Container contentPane) {
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    contentPane.add(button1());
    contentPane.add(button2());
    contentPane.add(button3());
}

private JButton button1() {
    JButton result = new JButton("button1");
    result.addActionListener(e -> displayWindow1());
    return result;
}

private void displayWindow1() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Window 1");
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private JButton button2() {
    JButton result = new JButton("button2");
    result.addActionListener(e -> displayWindow2());
    return result;
}

private void displayWindow2() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Window 2");
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private JButton button3() {
    JButton result = new JButton("button3");
    result.addActionListener(e -> displayWindow3());
    return result;
}

private void displayWindow3() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Window 3");
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

When you execute the `run()` method, this will display the main window. The main window contains three buttons, added by the method `populateMain()`. When you click any of the three buttons, a new window is created and displayed. You can also click each button multiple times. When you close the main window, the application is terminated. This is because of the following line:

```
    result.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I hope this helps you to get started. However this is just a simple example using Java's GUI framework called Swing. If you want to create a game you might want to use another GUI framework.